# Why can I successfully AJAX Get request fonts.googleapis.com (and not cnn.com)?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Why can I successfully AJAX Get request fonts.googleapis.com (and not cnn.com) ?

Maybe Google allowed the access and CNN does not.. Is there a way that I can make my website 'AJAXable' like fonts.google.com? Thank you very much!

Comment: CORS is the system that allows one domain to request resources from another, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS.

Answer (score 1):

Because Google allows access via Cross-Origin Resource Sharing ([spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) | [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)). Which is also how you would allow access to your content from other websites via ajax.

Essentially, you have your server respond to not just the usual `GET` request but also to an `OPTIONS` request and, in both case, include appropriate response headers (including but not limited to `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`) to allow the requesting site access, which is denied by default at the browser level.

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much! Have a nice day